Horror movie with bloody bodybag in the attic
I remember many years ago when I was younger ( I guess about 15 years ago) I remember to have woken up in the middle of the night. And as I was unable to sleep anymore I decided to turn on the TV and clicket throught the channel when I stopped at a certain movie. I only watched that single scene and it terrified me back then but was also, what I believe to today, one of the main reasons for my love for horror movies and jump scares today. I would love to watch that scene again just for the nostalgic reason but I was unable to find it ever since. I looked for it some time ago but was unable to find it back then.
So this might have been a movie or perhaps a TV show. I can only tell you about the scene like I remember it...
In this scene a person comes home, I think it was a woman. She enters her house, closes the door and then there is a stair to her left. I think the shot was filmed from the other side from the top corner of the room so you were able to see it from above. I think she had some groceries with her (although I am unsure about that). But she walks up the stairs and there is a hatch, these covers with the stair added where you pull on a string and then it opens to the attic. And as she pulls on the string the cover opens and a bag with a bloody body falls out covering the floor in blood as she starts to scream. 
I know this isn't much but back then I had to switch it off after that happened. If someone has any suggestion I would be really happy to know. I think something similar happened in Black Christmas but I only saw the newer version and I dont really believe that I watched it after 2006 so it could be the original one. Perhaps someone has seen the movie and can tell me if the scene appeared there. 
As the rules state that I have to mention a country of release I'd go with US, because this type of of house and the attic construction is typical for the US. 
